# invalid number of rows in section 0

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a thread problem SIGABRT when i try to add one more cell in my app; That is the exception which Xcode gave me:

> Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (0) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (0), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out).

That is the code where i consider is the problem

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    PlayerCell *cell = (PlayerCell *)[tableView
                                      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"PlayerCell"];
    Player *player = [self.players objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.nameLabel.text = player.name;
    cell.gameLabel.text = player.game;
    cell.ratingImageView.image = [self
                                  imageForRating:player.rating];
    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
    {
        [self.players removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];   }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.players count];
}
```

UPD.

I have an array in AppDelegate to preconfig several cells (to show user, how it looks like) and full it with follow code:

```
_players = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:20]; // make an array in appdelegate
Player *player = [[Player alloc] init]; //
player.name = @"Bill Evans";            //
player.game = @"Tic-Tac-Toe";           //Make new player
player.rating = 4;                      //
[_players addObject:player];            //Add in array in AppDelegate
PlayersViewController *playersViewController = [PlayersViewController new]; //Make instance for main array
playersViewController.players = _players; //add new item from appDelegate array to main
```

Another piece of code where the mistake may be (it loads when user taps on save button to add new cell)

```
    - (void)playerDetailsViewController:
(PlayerDetailsViewController *)controller
                       didAddPlayer:(Player *)player
{
    [self.players addObject:player];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath =
    [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[self.players count] - 1 inSection:0];
    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:
     [NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]
                          withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

So can anyone tell me, where is my mistake? If needed, i can send further code.

Thanks.

Comment: That isn't where the problem is because the error says a row was inserted and your shown code is for deletion.

Comment: Is property players static array or can it be reconstructed again at table refresh?

Comment: Could you provide your code for - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section;

Comment: try to reload the data `[self.tableView reloadData];` and make sure players array is mutable

Comment: @meda this didn't help. And one more thing to mention: when i try to fullfill one cell in AppDelegate.m `Player *player = [[Player alloc] init];
 player.name = @"Bill Evans";
 player.game = @"Tic-Tac-Toe";
 player.rating = 4;
 [_players addObject:player]; `

Nothing happens too (it doesn't show).